# VBA error 1004 on For Each statement

Tags: excel, vba

so I'm new to the VBA coding world and im building a productivity tracker for work just to help out.
the outcome is for the code to paste an excel formula in a cell however the cell will be referenced by 2 separate ranges which in turn create the individual sheets.

My code is probably unnecessarily bulky at the moment but im trying.

at the moment i am getting an error 1004 on the first 'For Each' statement.

would really appreciate some help on this one. thanks

```
Sub InsertStatsFormula()
Dim cellno As Excel.Range
Dim cell2 As Excel.Range
Dim Ptracker As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsTStats As Excel.Worksheet
Dim OutcomeColNo As Integer
Dim RowNo As Integer


Set Ptracker = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTStats = Ptracker.Worksheets("Team Stats")
RowNo = 5
With Ptracker
For Each cellno In Ptracker.Worksheets("Setup").Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell2 In Worksheets("Setup").Range("G11", Range("G11").End(xlDown))
        OutcomeColNo = wsTStats.Cells.Find(What:=cell2.Value, After:=[b4], SearchDirection:=xlToRight).Column
        wsTStats.Cells(RowNo, OutcomeColNo) = "=" & wsTStats.Cells(RowNo, 2) & "!I" & OutcomeColNo
    Next cell2

RowNo = RowNo + 1
Next cellno
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that your `Range("B8").End(xlDown)` doesn't specify which sheet in which to perform the `Range("B8").End(xlDown)`. Try instead:

`Ptracker.Worksheets("Setup").Range("B8", Ptracker.Worksheets("Setup").Range("B8").End(xlDown))`

You'll need to change this in your next `For Each` statement as well.

Lastly, VBA is a bulky language. Your code looks good for being new to the language.